# Postfix - how to reject all email with a 450 response code?

Tags: email, postfix

I am going to be migrating my email from one server to a new one.

During the migration I would like the old server to reject all incoming email, but with a code 450 so that the sending servers will try again later (after migration).

Can this be done with Postfix configuration?